# HOW select min from cast varchar to int in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to convert varchar into double value in mysql

See, i have table column in varchar but it has only numbers. In that i want to select min max of the value.

Please check the below query, in which I'm getting a syntax error.

```
select 
    MAX(CAST(ch1 as INT)) as max_ch1,
    MIN(CAST(ch1 as INT)) as min_ch1 
from t9;
```

Please refer to below [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/352f58/1)

Comment: wwwhhhyyyy? :-( SELECT MIN(ch1+0),MAX(ch1+0) FROM t9;

Comment: Please format the code part for a better view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
  MIN(CAST(CH1 AS SIGNED)),
  MAX(CAST(CH1 AS SIGNED))
FROM t9
```

Working SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4bbe/9).

You have to CAST the value as `SIGNED`, which corresponds to `INTEGER` in MySQL. More information about this, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Answer (score 7):

You can force an automatic numeric cast when using an operation like adding

```
select MAX(ch1+0) as max_ch1,
       MIN(ch1+0) as min_ch1 
from t9
```