# Django 1.6 + MySQL : Type Cast MySQL variable to search for Max, Avg

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm, django-aggregation

My Model is sort of like

```
class ServiceUtilization(models.Model):
device_name = models.CharField()
service_name = models.CharField()
data_source = models.CharField()
current_value = models.CharField()
sys_timestamp = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, here `current_value` represents the value in Float stored as VarChar, w.r.t the time stored as unixtime

While trying to get Max and Average values of `current_value` I am getting unexpected results, because for Max, MySQL would do a string based comparision, where in `'100' value < '9.99'` which in incorrect w.r.t values taken in Float.

I tried :

```
perf = ServiceUtilization.objects.filter(
        device_name__in=devices,
        service_name__in=services,
        data_source__in=data_sources,
        sys_timestamp__gte=start_date,
        sys_timestamp__lte=end_date
    ).values(
        'device_name',
        'service_name',
        'data_source'
    ).annotate(
        max_val=Max('current_value'),
        avg_val=Avg('current_value')
    )
```

It provides the incorrect results.

Then looking at : [HOW select min from cast varchar to int in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317404/how-select-min-from-cast-varchar-to-int-in-mysql)

I thought about providing query set with `extra`

```
perf = ServiceUtilization.objects.extra(
       select={
          'max_val': "MAX(CAST(current_value AS SIGNED))",
          'avg_val': "AVG(CAST(current_value AS SIGNED))"
       }
       ).filter(
        device_name__in=devices,
        service_name__in=services,
        data_source__in=data_sources,
        sys_timestamp__gte=start_date,
        sys_timestamp__lte=end_date
    ).values(
        'device_name',
        'service_name',
        'data_source',
        'max_val',
        'avg_val'
    )
```

But this just provides a single value and not desired results. This translates to SQL as

```
SELECT (MAX(CAST(current_value AS SIGNED))) AS `max_val`, (AVG(CAST(current_value AS SIGNED))) AS `avg_val`, `performance_utilizationstatus`.`device_name`, `performance_utilizationstatus`.`service_name`, `performance_utilizationstatus`.`data_source`
```

FROM `performance_utilizationstatus` ORDER BY `performance_utilizationstatus`.`sys_timestamp` DESC;

But the working code would require a GROUP BY on (device_name, service_name, data_source)

```
SELECT (MAX(CAST(current_value AS SIGNED))) AS `max_val`, (AVG(CAST(current_value AS SIGNED))) AS `avg_val`, `performance_utilizationstatus`.`device_name`, `performance_utilizationstatus`.`service_name`, `performance_utilizationstatus`.`data_source`  FROM `performance_utilizationstatus`
```

GROUP BY `performance_utilizationstatus`.`device_name`, `performance_utilizationstatus`.`service_name`,
`performance_utilizationstatus`.`data_source`
ORDER BY `performance_utilizationstatus`.`sys_timestamp` DESC;

How to add the GROUP BY CLAUSE ?

Using `annotate` would not work here

`1111, 'Invalid use of group function'`

or

`ERROR 1056 (42000): Can't group on 'max_val'`

Would RAW SQL be the last resort here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must go with `.raw` because using `.extra` wont be possible here.

The problem is because `Django` don't have `.group_by` the only way go group by something is to use `.values` and `.annotate` after that. (*as you have done it in the first attempt*)

so.. why you can't use `.extra` ? Because:

> Any extra() call made after a values() call will have its extra
>   selected fields ignored.

and

> If you use a values() clause after an extra() call, any fields defined
>   by a select argument in the extra() must be explicitly included in the
>   values() call.

so the only way to get the `.extra` fields is to add them into `.values` but this will cause to group by this fields which is an undesired behavior.